# gwtplatform rpc dispatch cross domain request

Tags: java, rpc, gwtp

Can I perform cross domain request in GWTP RPC Dispatch?

I need to do request from my front-end server to back-end server. At this moment in my local environment I need to perform request on different port e.g. from http://localhost:8090/app to http://localhost:8080/api. In production I'm going to do requests like mysite.com -> mysiteapi.com.

**UPD**

Please provide an description for what to do to get GWTP making request on another domain.

For pure GWT I need to have the code like this:

```
GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
(ServiceDefTarget)greetingService).setServiceEntryPoint("http://localhost:8888/mymodule/greet");
```

What about GWTP? Because by default GWTP does requests on the same domain. I use GIN/Guice.

Comment: Do your servers support CORS? See [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/TFZsxQIeQXs/cAs3uKbzZ84J) for example.

Comment: Yes, I use Tomcat on client and AppEngine on server side. Your link is useful but I'm a little confused how to use it with GWT-Platform.

Comment: This is **nothing** to do with GWT (with GWTP or otherwise), this is do with browser SOP. In order for a browser to allow a cross-origin request then server that the request is being made to must have a CORS policy to allow requests from the page's origin. So you need to configure a filter on your Tomcat server to serve CORS data.

Comment: I updated the question.